# Encountering an Error when trying to install application using ADB

Tags: android, installation, adb

I am trying to install the application using ADB. I am getting an error for file path. I checked many times and the path is correct. All other functions I am able to do using ADB like restarting, checking versions etc. but not able to install.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: what have you set the path to adb..

Comment: Are you getting path error on adb or the apk?

Comment: what is the path to your adb

Comment: Provide exact error message

Comment: Are there any spaces in the path?  If so, you will need to wrap the path in quotes

Comment: @android addict: no i do not have any spaces in the path

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have not set the path to

```
C:\...\...\tools\
```

and change to

```
C:\...\...\platform-tools
```

Comment: This assumes a Windows OS which the OP has not identified.

Comment: @prakhar I have set the path to c:\Users\desktop\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools\adb

Comment: i am able to get all the cmd promt syntax but i cannot run the apk file

Comment: where are you not able to run the apk

Comment: Hie.. I was successfully to enabled with telnet using the below link http://www.itdoescompute.com/2009/10/29/how-to-enable-telnet-in-windows-7/. But still i could not connect to my Android phone. Can anyone suggest me how to proceed?